# How to make ob/Highcharts work in a symfony3 project

Tags: symfony, highcharts

I am trying to integrate OBHighChartsBundle in my symfony project. I followed the tutorial at https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle.

My controller :

```
public function piechartAction()
{
    $data = [
        ['Microsoft Internet Explorer', 56.33],
        ['Chrome', 24.03],
        ['Firefox', 10.38],
        ['Safari', 4.77],
        ['Opera', 0.91],
        ['Proprietary or Undetectable', 0.2]
    ];

    $ob = new Highchart();
    $ob->chart->renderTo('container');
    $ob->chart->type('pie');
    $ob->title->text('My Pie Chart');
    $ob->series(array(array("data"=>$data)));

       return $this->render('CarteProassurBundle:Default:index.html.twig', [
        'mypiechart' => $ob
    ]);
}
```

My view :

```
<!-- Load jQuery from Google's CDN if needed -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/4.1.8/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    {{ chart(mypiechart)}}
</script>

<div id="linechart" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

I have a blank page and an error when i inspect the page :

highcharts.js:13 Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Value of `renderTo` should be the id of the div (which is `linechart` in your case (not `container`)).

Comment: Thanks a lot! this worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value of `renderTo` should be the id of the div (which is `linechart` in your case (not `container`)).